# "Transition" Variable in R

Tags: r

Lets say I have these data set:

```
library(data.table)
mydata <- data.table(year=1991:2000,
                     z=c(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0))
```

If I call the dataset, it will look something like this:

```
mydata
    year z
 1: 1991 0
 2: 1992 0
 3: 1993 1
 4: 1994 1
 5: 1995 1
 6: 1996 1
 7: 1997 1
 8: 1998 0
 9: 1999 0
10: 2000 0
```

What I need is:

1. A transition variable, call it `c`. If I had these dataset, it would look something like this:

`year z  c
     1: 1991 0  0
     2: 1992 0  0
     3: 1993 1  1
     4: 1994 1 NA
     5: 1995 1 NA
     6: 1996 1 NA
     7: 1997 1 NA
     8: 1998 0  0
     9: 1999 0  0
    10: 2000 0  0`

Essentially, `c` *marks* when there has been a **transition** in variable `z`, from  `z=0` to `z=1`. When it does, `c` puts a `1` just once and then starts putting `NA's` *until it returns to the original state* `(z=0)`. Then, it starts putting zeroes.

- I have another `id` variable, but that would complicate the example. I think I can manage that part.

** EDITED **: In fact, it does not matter whether I have an `id` variable or not.

It sounds easy, but not being a R expert myself, it's killing me!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `rleid` to create a group variable, and then replace duplicated `1` in `z` with `NA` using `ifelse` statement:

```
mydata[, c := ifelse(duplicated(z) & z == 1, NA_integer_, z), by = rleid(z)][]

#    year z  c
# 1: 1991 0  0
# 2: 1992 0  0
# 3: 1993 1  1
# 4: 1994 1 NA
# 5: 1995 1 NA
# 6: 1996 1 NA
# 7: 1997 1 NA
# 8: 1998 0  0
# 9: 1999 0  0
#10: 2000 0  0
```

Answer (score 3):

Another attempt:

```
mydata[, c := z]
mydata[c==1, c := replace(c,-1,NA), by=rleid(z)]

#    year z  c
# 1: 1991 0  0
# 2: 1992 0  0
# 3: 1993 1  1
# 4: 1994 1 NA
# 5: 1995 1 NA
# 6: 1996 1 NA
# 7: 1997 1 NA
# 8: 1998 0  0
# 9: 1999 0  0
#10: 2000 0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
mydata <- data.table(year=1991:2000, z=c(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0))
mydata[,c:=ifelse(z!=shift(z, type="lag"), 1, 0)]
mydata[1,]$c = 0
```

check this function in data.table `shift(x, n=1L, fill=NA, type=c("lag", "lead"), give.names=FALSE)` Shift function shifts x in both "lead" and "lag" direction. N is the number of steps. In the first comparison, NA is generated that has been changed to 0 in the last line. You can read `?shift` in your session and read more about this function.

Comment: Have you checked your output?

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain why and/or how it answers the question. Providing this additional context would significantly improve its long-term value. Please edit your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @jmattheis Hey, I guess your problem is solved by now. Don't you think you should accept the answer. In case, there is need of much explanation then let me know.

Comment: I'm not the OP. So I can't do this.

Comment: @hector-bahamonde You can check my answer. I guess, this solves your problem